# Helm Install failing without giving much information about the cause/

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am installing the mist.io chart which has below three chart dependencies

```
1. mongodb-12.1.19.tg
2. rabbitmq-10.1.5.tgz
3. victoria-metrics-cluster-0.8.24.tgz
```

However, when I try to install it, I am getting a failure error. the error message is not much help in identifying the issue.

command:

```
helm install test-staging chart/mist
```

Output:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(StatefulSet.spec.updateStrategy): invalid type for io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetUpdateStrategy: got "string", expected "map"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an issue with Kubernetes api version, where you are using a latest api with old helm chart and chart's values.yaml. Below is an indicative change of the `updateStrategy`, where it could be changed from:

```
updateStrategy: RollingUpdate
```

To:

```
updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
```

This worked for, where in my case I had an old version of **mysql** helm chart used for Kubernetes version 1.17 and tried to use it with Kubernetes version 1.19.

Please refer the relevant Kubernetes official documentation from here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#updating-statefulsets, before you make your changes.